# Exporting mean Sentinel-2 in Open Data Cube (ODC) for one time but multiple bands

Tags: open-data-cube

A mean for a month of sentinel 2 data was created for 8 different bands.

I want to write and download this image into a geotiff. But this code doesn't seem to work.

```
# Compute a single mean from all data
ds_mean = ds.mean('time')

from datacube.utils.cog import write_cog

rgb_tiff = ds_mean.to_array()

write_cog(rgb_tiff,
          fname='mean.tif',
          overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: My kernel is crashing when writing, I'm think that it needs to specify the specific time

Answer (score 1):

How large, in pixels, is your x and y dimensions? And how large is your compute environment? Often the kernel crashing means you've exceeded RAM.  And `write_cog` is very memory intensive (1.5-2 times the size of the file) as it produces overview images. See [here](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/utilities/generate/datacube.utils.cog.write_cog.html)

Comment: Yes I think that might be it. I think the y: 8673, x: 9466. So I'm trying to use the Lazy loading with Dask now to see if I can reduce the amount of memory needed